# How to create .apk file using eclipse or Android studio?

Tags: android, angularjs

I have created a application using angularjs and jquery. Now I want to create a .apk file for android. Can anyone help me for creating .apk file on windows operating system with Cordova js libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio **Build -> Build APK**